# Create N x M Tensor matrix with two Tensor vectors and apply a function for each (n,m) pair

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two Tensors X and Z of shape `(100,)` and I would like to create a Tensor X x Z which would result in a shape of `(100, 100)`.

And for each pair element within this matrix I'd like to apply some function that I have already defined, i.e. fn(x,z) for each possible combination in the matrix.

I am new to TensorFlow and I'm used to thinking sequentially, with two for loops over each vector when dealing with numpy arrays.

How can I do this in TensorFlow? Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want that solution to work for any function `fn(x,z)`, or do you have a example in mind? The answer would change whether the function is linearly separable or not.

Comment: @Lescurel Thanks for the response. The function itself is non-linear and used to calculate the co-variance between x and z. I am trying to calculate the co-variance matrix for a Gaussian Process, hence would like to apply it to every pair in a matrix form.

Comment: It would be easier to give an answer with an example of the function. If `fn` is just a composition of simple mathematical functions, e.g. `fn = lambda x, z: tf.exp(tf.sin(x) / (tf.square(z) + 1))`, you would just need to use broadcasting like `fn(tf.expand_dims(x, 1), z)`.

Answer (score 2):

## For the general question

You could create a custom layer to solve this.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer


def fn(x, y):
    return x + y


class PairMatrix(Layer):
    def __init__(self, func=None):
        super(PairMatrix, self).__init__()
        self.func = func

    def call(self, inputs, **kwargs):
        X, Y = tf.meshgrid(inputs[0], inputs[1])
        return self.func(X, Y)


x = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])
y = tf.constant([1, 2, 3])

z = PairMatrix(func=fn).apply([x, y])
```

This *should* create a layer that takes a function as argument. When called, the function will be applied on the constructed mesh of input x and y.

In the simple test case above, the output produced is:

```py
z = tf.Tensor([[2 3 4]
               [3 4 5]
               [4 5 6]], shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32)
```

## Regarding your commment

If it's only the covariance that you are interested in, you could use [`tfp.stats.covariance`](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/stats/covariance)